# How to Display .raw Dataset?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script to display the images in the file *burned_wood_with_tape_1664x512x256_12bit.raw* from this website: https://figshare.com/articles/SSOCT_test_dataset_for_OCTproZ/12356705

for a research project. However, I can't find a way to display the images in this *.raw* dataset.

This is the software I have, using other questions on StackOverflow:

```
import rawpy
import imageio

path = "Datasets/burned_wood_with_tape_1664x512x256_12bit.raw"
for item in path:
    item_path = path + item
    raw = rawpy.imread(item_path)
    rgb = raw.postprocess()
    rawpy.imshow(rgb)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[ENTER PATH]", line 7, in <module>
    raw = rawpy.imread(item_path)
  File "[ENTER PATH]\lib\site-packages\rawpy\__init__.py", line 20, in imread
    d.open_file(pathOrFile)
  File "rawpy\_rawpy.pyx", line 404, in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.open_file
  File "rawpy\_rawpy.pyx", line 914, in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.handle_error
rawpy._rawpy.LibRawIOError: b'Input/output error'
```

Comment: can you see the content of the file (i.e. raw image) on your computer? if so, with what program? what is your OS?

Comment: @AminGheibi The "file" is a dataset, which I can't view without a script. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: It's a few hundred medical images which I'm not able to view without writing a program.

Comment: So, I guess there is confusion here. Files with extension ".raw" are specific file extensions for raw photos out of digital cameras. If that is a set of files (maybe it is compressed) you should contact the dataset owner to see how to open the set and access each individual file. That "rawpy" library is for reading raw files, not for datasets.

Comment: In the description of the dataset (the link that you have posted), it is mentioned that you can use this SSOCT raw data with the "Virtual OCT System" of OCTproZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that you have is not a ".raw" file. It is a dataset that can be used with the "Virtual OCT System" of OCTproZ (https://github.com/spectralcode/OCTproZ/). The "rawpy" library is not useful in this case. That library works for ".raw" photos.